# Difficulty in Text Alignment HTML

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

The Text on page Except that **Troll Malayalam** Heading , all other text aligns to the middle of screen,Can anyone tell me the reason for it

My Code is given below

Some css were also associated with the file which was written by my friend.I don't know whether this's making the problem.(This was written so as to make the **Troll Malayalam** text to be in middle of the violet icon at starting and for some adjustments to div amd image).That css is given below

```css
img {
  outline: none;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.main {
  outline: none;
  background: white;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  height: auto;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: 0;
}
.footer_cnt img {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.footer_cnt a {
  color: #000000;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}
.footer_cnt span {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer_cnt">
      <img
        src="https://scontent.fcok1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-1/p720x720/84111402_2811061845582960_154567974538182656_n.jpg?_nc_cat=1&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=dbb9e7&_nc_ohc=ihulZ5OK3PIAX-l1LDw&_nc_ht=scontent.fcok1-1.fna&oh=b79534f76c601b8021f624031fa8c734&oe=616CA9AB"
        height="50"
        width="50"
        style="border: 0px solid #cacaca; display: inline-block"
      /><span class="text">&nbsp Troll Malayalam</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p align="left">
    SED ആക്കിയല്ലോ <br />
    © A k H i L (Troll Malayalam)
  </p>
  <br />
  <img
    style="width: 100%; height: auto"
    src="https://scontent.fcok1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/p526x296/242233471_4487946741227787_7604896157043718753_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=110474&_nc_ohc=A7fWT3N-pTsAX9W9Ub0&_nc_ht=scontent.fcok1-1.fna&oh=0d61346f219d8997e50e7e54fcfaae0f&oe=616BB3D7"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Malayali ? So you are trying to make the whole texts into the center or to the left ? How do you expect it to be >

Comment: Yeah Bro, I Expect the texts to be aligned Left

Comment: I have added an answer. Check it and let me know in case if you need further assistance.

Comment: Anytime, hoping to see this website around, and get laughed. All the best

Comment: @AbinThaha Sure :), Thanks You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem was the text's are aligned in the center, then here you go.

I have removed the `float: left` from your code (4 places). And now it seems to be making sense to me. Check now, if you want the texts to be aligned to the center, you can now give `text-align` property to do so also.

```css
img {
  outline: none;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.main {
  outline: none;
  background: white;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  height: auto;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: 0;
}
.footer_cnt img {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
.footer_cnt a {
  color: #000000;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}
.footer_cnt span {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer_cnt">
      <img
        src="https://scontent.fcok1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-1/p720x720/84111402_2811061845582960_154567974538182656_n.jpg?_nc_cat=1&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=dbb9e7&_nc_ohc=ihulZ5OK3PIAX-l1LDw&_nc_ht=scontent.fcok1-1.fna&oh=b79534f76c601b8021f624031fa8c734&oe=616CA9AB"
        height="50"
        width="50"
        style="border: 0px solid #cacaca; display: inline-block"
      /><span class="text">&nbsp Troll Malayalam</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p align="left">
    SED ആക്കിയല്ലോ <br />
    © A k H i L (Troll Malayalam)
  </p>
  <br />
  <img
    style="width: 100%; height: auto"
    src="https://scontent.fcok1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/p526x296/242233471_4487946741227787_7604896157043718753_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=110474&_nc_ohc=A7fWT3N-pTsAX9W9Ub0&_nc_ht=scontent.fcok1-1.fna&oh=0d61346f219d8997e50e7e54fcfaae0f&oe=616BB3D7"
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p >SED ആക്കിയല്ലോ  <br> © A k H i L(Troll Malayalam)</p> 
<br>



p {text-align:left}
```

Comment: Brief explanation of how the code works will greatly improve the answer

Answer (score 0):

> **Disclaimer :** This post is not in favor of trolling and you too are advised not to troll

To `center-align` `SED ആക്കിയല്ലോ <br />© A k H i L (Troll Malayalam)` just change :

```
<p align="left">
    SED ആക്കിയല്ലോ <br />
    © A k H i L (Troll Malayalam)
  </p>
```

**to**

```
<p align="center">
    SED ആക്കിയല്ലോ <br />
    © A k H i L (Troll Malayalam)
  </p>
```

If you want to add Troll Malayalam at top and `background-color: yellow`
Then add this to your code :
**Html**

```
<div class="contentContainer">
<h2 class="contentHead">Troll Malyalam</h2>
<!--Your initialhtml code goes here-->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box
}
.contentContainer{
  background-color:yellow;
  padding:10px;
}
.contentHead{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```css
img {
  outline: none;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.main {
  outline: none;
  background: white;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  height: auto;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: 0;
}
.footer_cnt img {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.footer_cnt a {
  color: #000000;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}
.footer_cnt span {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer_cnt">
      <img
        src="https://scontent.fcok1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-1/p720x720/84111402_2811061845582960_154567974538182656_n.jpg?_nc_cat=1&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=dbb9e7&_nc_ohc=ihulZ5OK3PIAX-l1LDw&_nc_ht=scontent.fcok1-1.fna&oh=b79534f76c601b8021f624031fa8c734&oe=616CA9AB"
        height="50"
        width="50"
        style="border: 0px solid #cacaca; display: inline-block"
      /><span class="text">&nbsp Troll Malayalam</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p align="center">
    SED ആക്കിയല്ലോ <br />
    © A k H i L (Troll Malayalam)
  </p>
  <br />
  <img
    style="width: 100%; height: auto"
    src="https://scontent.fcok1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/p526x296/242233471_4487946741227787_7604896157043718753_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=110474&_nc_ohc=A7fWT3N-pTsAX9W9Ub0&_nc_ht=scontent.fcok1-1.fna&oh=0d61346f219d8997e50e7e54fcfaae0f&oe=616BB3D7"
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You should change your layout,

```css
img {
  outline: none;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}

.main {
  outline: none;
  background: white;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  height: auto;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer_cnt img {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.footer_cnt a {
  color: #000000;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.footer_cnt span {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.text {
  float: left;
  line-height: 27px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer_cnt">
      <img
        src="https://scontent.fcok1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-1/p720x720/84111402_2811061845582960_154567974538182656_n.jpg?_nc_cat=1&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=dbb9e7&_nc_ohc=ihulZ5OK3PIAX-l1LDw&_nc_ht=scontent.fcok1-1.fna&oh=b79534f76c601b8021f624031fa8c734&oe=616CA9AB"
        height="50"
        width="50"
        style="border: 0px solid #cacaca; display: inline-block"
      /><div class="text">
      <div>Troll Malayalam</div>
      <div> SED ആക്കിയല്  ോ </div>
      <p>
    © A k H i L (Troll Malayalam)
  </p>
      </div>
       
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <br />
  <img
    style="width: 100%; height: auto"
    src="https://scontent.fcok1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/p526x296/242233471_4487946741227787_7604896157043718753_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=110474&_nc_ohc=A7fWT3N-pTsAX9W9Ub0&_nc_ht=scontent.fcok1-1.fna&oh=0d61346f219d8997e50e7e54fcfaae0f&oe=616BB3D7"
  />
</div>
```